# When completing a subdialog in the Microsoft Bot framework V4, how do you continue on the parent dialog?

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework

**Introduction**

Currently I'm trying to create a Bot Framework application using the Microsoft Bot Framework v4.

**Structure of program**

We currently have the following setup:

The root of the bot class is named: `SubDialogBotBot`

Within the `SubDialogBot` we create a new Dialog named `ParentDialog`. This Dialog is responsible for reacting to a specific Intent.

We then start a new Dialog from the `ParentDialog` named `ChildDialog`. This child dialog will be responsible for asking the user a question based on arguments passed by `ParentDialog`.

After this question completed we want to return to the `ParentDialog` and continue the flow.

In this example we want to re-use the `ChildDialog` from all kinds of different intents as the code in here is exactly the same. The only thing that changes is the questions that have to be asked to the user.

**Problem**

When the `ChildDialog` completes the 'flow' is never returned to the `ParentDialog`.

We also tried to have the Dialog following after the `ChildDialog` ID set to something specific and then call this using Context.BeginDialog(....) from the `ChildDialog`. However because apparently the dialog was added to the `ParentDialog` and not to the `ChildDialog` it can't find this by the id.

**Github repository reproducing the problem**

https://github.com/devedse/SubDialogBotReproduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is an awesomely prepared question, thank you... especially for sharing the code.

Now, the good news is I don't think I see any problem with your dialogs. The problem is actually in [your bot's `OnTurnAsync`](https://github.com/devedse/SubDialogBotReproduction/blob/5eed87cc51bff8d5f8c954098cc406c0b74aa240/SubDialogBot/SubDialogBot.cs#L75-L95). You are only ever calling `BeginDialogAsync` on your `ParentDialog`. Every single activity is going to come in through your `OnTurnAsync` and that means you're responsible for handling re-entrancy into the dialog stack. This means that, you need to check for an active dialog and, if there is one, you need to be calling `ContinueDialogAsync` instead to resume from where the discussion left off. Here's your current `OnTurnAsync` with the extra checks added:

```cs
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // Create a dialog context
    var dc = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);

    // Handle Message activity type, which is the main activity type for shown within a conversational interface

    // Message activities may contain text, speech, interactive cards, and binary or unknown attachments.

    // see https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types

    if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        // If there's no active dialog, begin the parent dialog
        if(dc.ActivDialog == null)
        {
           await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ParentDialog));
        }
        else
        {
           await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();
        }


        // Save the new turn count into the conversation state.
        await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
    }
    else
    {

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{turnContext.Activity.Type} event detected");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Devedse - I wonder if you're used to V3, where you continue dialogs or begin a new one with the same line

Comment: @Drew Marsh, thanks for your answer. However, implementing your code didn't solve the issue. The ParentDialog seems to just get ended after the waterfall step and the child dialog never called.

I rewrote the code a little which (I think) should do the same thing. Check our commit: https://github.com/devedse/SubDialogBotReproduction/commit/fb838cdf21dc0904f56fdb05cdf42b8e4b0fcb5b

Comment: So right now I see this code executing and doing what I would expect which is showing the two messages from the `ParentDialog` that you send from the waterfall steps. You don't actually invoke the `ChildDialog` anywhere right now. What you'd maybe want to do is call `BeginDialogAsync` to start the `ChildDialog` in the first waterfall step and then when the child finishes it should return to the parent and execute the next waterfall step there.

Comment: Ah ok, so the first dialog that was added to the Dialogs of a form will be automatically invoked, and any subsequent needs to be invoked by calling BeginDialogAsync?

Comment: Yes, that's the default behavior, but you _can_ also explicitly control which child is invoked first by setting `InitialDialogId` in the constructor of your `ComponentDialog` subclass.